# Jquery - Check if there is a connection to server with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am writing a web app using JQuery. I want to check if the code can access the server before processing stuff. Here is my function:

```
function CheckServerStatus() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "website.asmx/CheckStatus",
        async:false
        success: function() {return true;}
        error: function() {return false;}
    });
}
```

In the server side code, the `CheckStatus` function return 1. And the function is called something like this:

```
function RunProcess() {
    if (CheckServerStatus()) {
        //Do work
    }
    else {
        //create alert
    }
}
```

Every time the function is called. The function, `CheckServerStatus` returns false.

I want the function to return true if the ajax function success connects to the server.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with callbacks and also make it async

In the function CheckServerStatus register 2 parameters

The 1st will be the success handler

and the 2nd the errorHandler

and then connect each one with $.ajax success and error callbacks

```
function CheckServerStatus(successHandler,errorHandler) {
   $.ajax({
            url: "website.asmx/CheckStatus",
            async:true,
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
        });
}

 function RunProcess() {
    CheckServerStatus(

        function(){
            alert('we will do work here');
        }, 
        function(){
            alert('failed to connect');
        }
    )
 }
```